# zabbix triger does not set the trigger to the ok state when using no data

Tags: zabbix

I am unable to return the trigger to the resolved state using no data and other keys.

the trigger works fine when the condition is reached, but if the device was turned off and no data is received, then the trigger remains hanging in the problem state
problem expression:

```
last(/_custom proverki/proc.num[AnyDesk.exe])>=3
```

recovery expression:

```
nodata(/_custom proverki/proc.num[AnyDesk.exe],1m,"strict")=1
```

It has been hanging for 3 days

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not framing the question correctly.I'm new to asking questions.